# R: Write for loop to calculate difference and store in new variable

Tags: r, variables, for-loop

I have looked at different questions asked about this topic, but none helped me so far in getting what I want.

I have a dataframe, with two variables (standardized_'testname') and 'predicted_standardized_'testname'). Now, I want to calculate the difference between the two and store that in a new variable, called 'testname'_finalscore.

Since I have about 19 different tests, I want to do this with a for loop in R - But i'm new to writing these kind of loops, and i'm stuck.

I have a testlist, with all the names of the separate tests:

```
testlist <- c("vlgt_ltfr", "vlgt_recog", 
          "vlgt_imrec", "wms_imrec", 
          "wms_delrec", "fluency_dier", 
          "fluency_beroep", "tapdom",
          "tapndom", "traila", "trailb",
          "erik_congruent", "erik_percincong",
          "erik_incongruent", "stroop_baseline",
          "stroop_interference", "subrs", "tmt_interference")
```

Over this, I have written a loop to calculate the standardized and predicted_standardized scores.

Example:

```
for( test in testlist){
      patdat[,paste0('standardized_',test)] <- (patdat[,test] - tempmean) / tempsd
      patdat[,paste0('predicted_standardized_',test)] <- coef(mymod)[1] + coef(mymod)[2]*patdat[,'p_age'] + coef(mymod)[3]*patdat[,'nlviq']
```

}

After this, I created different loops (which don't work) in which I *try* to calculate the difference and store it in a new variable:

```
for( test in testlist){
  normdata[,paste0(test,'_finalscore')] <- (normdata[,paste0('standardized_', test)] - normdata[,paste0('predicted_standardized_', test)])
 }

for(test in testlist){
  normdata[,paste0(test, '_finalscore')] <- normdata[get('standardized_',test)] - normdata[get('predicted_standardized_'), test]
}

for(test in testlist){
  normdata[,paste0(test, '_finalscore')] <- (normdata['standardized_',test] - normdata['predicted_standardized_', test])
}
```

I do get a variable with 'testname'_finalscore, however it is empty. I think i'm indexing wrong and that there might be a function that I can use to solve this problem - but I haven't found it yet.

**EXAMPLE OF DATA**

```
> normdata$standardized_subrs
 [1] -0.45551  0.61058  0.18414  0.18414 -0.13568 -1.30838  0.39736
 [8]  0.71719 -0.13568 -0.13568  0.29075  0.18414  1.99649 -1.62821

> normdata$predicted_standardized_subrs
 [1] -0.458274  0.174143 -0.492066 -0.414063  0.081612  0.488208
 [7]  0.399994  0.416249 -0.113008 -0.398671  0.943571  0.316543
```

What I want to get is a variable "subrs_finalscore" that looks like this, but for all tests in testlist:

```
> normdata$standardized_subrs - normdata$predicted_standardized_subrs
 [1]  0.002764  0.436435  0.676208  0.598205 -0.217296 -1.796589
 [7] -0.002633  0.300938 -0.022676  0.262987 -0.652819 -0.132400
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `normdata <- data.frame(
  standardized_subrs = c(-0.45551, 0.61058, 0.18414),
  predicted_standardized_subrs = c(-0.458274, 0.174143, -0.492066)
) ;
testlist <- c("subrs") ;
for( test in testlist){
  normdata[,paste0(test,'_finalscore')] <- 
    (normdata[,paste0('standardized_', test)] - 
       normdata[,paste0('predicted_standardized_', test)])
}` works on my side. Does it on yours? If not, what's the problem (error)?

Comment: It works here as well! No clue why it didn't before, maybe a typo or something... Thank you! Couldn't get my head around what was going wrong.

Comment: you don't have the same amount of observations in `standardized_subrs
` and `predicted_standardized_subrs` in your example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have `standardized` and `predicted_standardized` columns in our data frame for each test. This is a hard form to work with to get the answer to your question.

We want to calculate the difference between two numbers and store it. What if the data looked like this:

```
TestName Standardized Predicted
subrs        -0.45551 -0.458274
subrs         0.61058  0.174143
subrs         0.18414 -0.492066
...
```

Instead of storing the data in a wide format with many columns (two columns for each test) we store it in a long format with only three columns: The name of the test, the standardized value, and the predicted value. This is called `tidying` the data, or putting it in `tidy` format.

If we had data in `tidy` format in a frame called `tidy_data`, then calculating the difference is as easy as...

```
library(tidyverse)
tidy_data %>% mutate(FinalScore = Predicted - Standardized)
```

`mutate` adds a new column to the frame with the calculated value.

So how do we get it in `tidy` form? It's a little work, but if we take the original wide data frame and change it like so...

```
tidy_data = data %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row_num) %>%
  mutate(IsPredicted = ifelse(grepl("predicted", key), "Predicted", "Standardized"),
         TestName = gsub("predicted_standardized_|standardized_", "", key)) %>%
  select(TestName, IsPredicted, value, row_num) %>%
  spread(IsPredicted, value) %>%
  select(-row_num)
```

We get the tidy form we're after.

Comment: I remember reading about the 3rd normal form and its benefits somewhere... :)